# Ambiguous Sql Error From VS-2005

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

It is serious matters: is it fault in Sql Query Analyzer?.

I have face strange situation that I have tested following query on Sql Query  Analyzer:

```
insert into PLCommonTotal(CmnTotal)
select
case
when p.NetpurTot > s.NetsalTot then
(
select NetpurTot from PLPurchaseTotal
)
else
(
Select NetsalTot from PLSaleTotal
)
end
from PLPurchaseTotal p
join PLSaleTotal s
on p.companyID=s.companyID

select * from PLCommonTotal
```

It is working very well no error from Sql Query Analyzer.

Now look at the same query in VS-2005 :

```
string tot5 = " insert into PLCommonTotal(CmnTotal)" +
                " select" +
                " case" +
                " when p.NetpurTot > s.NetsalTot then" +
                " (" +
                " select NetpurTot from PLPurchaseTotal" +
                " )" +
                " else" +
                " (" +
                " Select NetsalTot from PLSaleTotal" +
                " )" +
                " end" +
                " from PLPurchaseTotal p" +
                " join PLSaleTotal s" +
                " on p.companyID=s.companyID";
            SqlCommand comcmd = new SqlCommand(tot5, con);
            comcmd.Transaction = trans;
            comcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is throw Sql Error : **“ subquery return more than one value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows = != < <= > >= or when the subquery used an expression. The statement has been termited”.**

I want to ask the question if it is not permitted than why it is executed from SQL Query analyzer without any error?.

Is there fault of SQL Team?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written the query this will happen if you have more than one row in either `PLPurchaseTotal` or `PLSaleTotal`. I think that you are not using the same DB in SSMS and in VS-2005.

On the other hand i suspect that this is the query you are aiming for.

```
insert into PLCommonTotal(CmnTotal)
select
  case
    when p.NetpurTot > s.NetsalTot
    then p.NetpurTot
    else s.NetsalTot
  end
from PLPurchaseTotal p
  join PLSaleTotal s
    on p.companyID=s.companyID
```

Comment: Yes it is I have used it later but it's not my question. As per your statement If I am using Sql Server-2000 than it could create problem in VS-2005 as there Sql-2005 tools

Comment: ... Did you say like there are diferent mechanism betweem sql server-2000 and 2005 for transact sql.

Comment: @mahesh - No there is no difference between db-versions. It is a matter of what data the tables contain so I think you use different databases with different content. Your original query does not show any error if the tables have less then two rows in them. When you specify the table name in the sub query you are using the entire table *again*, not the table you have specified in the from clause of the main query.

Comment: I think You are right but if it is so than why it's not throw error from Sql Query Anaylzer why it is executed without error that's important thing which i accepted from you to answer?.

Comment: @mahesh - From my answer "I think that you are not using the same DB". And by that I mean that you are not using the same database when you execute your query with SQL Query Analyzer.

Comment: If so than is it possible to view the data of table by select command on Sql query analyzer?.

Comment: ... The my DB name is maa and the same used it at Sql Query analyzer and VS-2005.

Comment: @mahesh - To view data just do `select * from TableName`. Could you be using different servers?